# how can i logout from this website (http://aviation.stackexchange.com/)?

Tags: discussion

I don't have can detailed version of this question. All I want to know for now is how to logout from the current website in which I have asked this question.

Comment: Hi, Taha. Only questions that are actually about aviation should be posted here. Questions about use of the site should be posted [on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) . This particular question [has already been answered on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-to-logout-from-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 3):

Click the top left stack exchange icon. It should say log out next to the community in which you are currently logged in.